# Can windows 7 cmd.exe properties be set for current window only

Tags: windows-7, command-line

With XP, when the window properties were changed on a cmd.exe session, there was a little dialog box that offered "Apply properties to current window only" vs "Save properties for future windows with same title". It pretty much did what it offered, except that the latter really wasn't about the window title per se, it was for windows started by the same shortcut, but that's beside the point.

The problem is, in windows 7, any changes to cmd.exe properties seem to apply to all windows started by the same shortcut. Period. No option to do it to just the "current window only". Sometimes when I'm messing around and have several sessions open, it helps to change the font colors to visually identify one from another. On win 7 this becomes impossible to do without messing up the saved settings for whatever shortcut started the window.

So is this something that can be achieved with a registry setting somewhere, or something in the policy editor? Or is this just one of those features that they decided to leave out?

Comment: You can create few shortcuts like this: "cmd.exe /t xy" where x is foreground color, y is background color. You can find cmd color table by googling it.

Comment: the question is not how to launch them with different colors, it's given that a session is already started, and you use the gui to alter anything in the 'properties' dialog (e.g. color, but also font/layout), how do get it to *not* stick the change to future windows, i.e., to do it only to the current one.

Comment: I know thats a bit off-topic, thats why I put that in comment.

Comment: Maybe, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905911/2861476) can help